How can I play a gsm file in the browser
I have a (voicemail) .gsm file that I need to play in the browser. Html5 does not support .gsm files. How can I play it so the user can hear his voicemails?
The .gsm files I used to get from a specic provider, I convert on the fly with this code:
Imports NAudio.Wave
Function ConvertGsm610ToPcm(inputBytes As Byte()) As Byte()
 Using gsmStream As New MemoryStream(inputBytes)
     Using gsmReader As New WaveFileReader(gsmStream)
         If gsmReader.WaveFormat.Encoding = WaveFormatEncoding.Gsm610 Then
             Using pcmStream As New MemoryStream()
                 Using pcmWriter As New WaveFileWriter(pcmStream, New WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1))
                     Dim gsmFormat As New Gsm610WaveFormat()
                     Dim gsmToPcmStream As New WaveFormatConversionStream(pcmWriter.WaveFormat, gsmReader)
                     gsmToPcmStream.CopyTo(pcmWriter)
                     Return pcmStream.ToArray()
                 End Using
             End Using
         Else
             Return inputBytes
         End If
     End Using
 End Using
End Function

This code works fine. But now I'm working with another provider, and when I try to use the former function, I get:

Not a WAVE file - no RIFF header

I tried many different variations of waveformats etc, but can't get a working file. Either the play buttons don't turn on in the chrome audio player, or I hear 3 seconds of static noise, or 31 seconds of bubbling sounds. The sample file itself is 31 seconds.
Double clicking on the file on my pc works perfectly. Plays with VLC player.
Here are the details of the file as displayed by VLC player:
codec: gsm audio (gsm)
type: audio
channels:mono
sample rate:8000 hz
bits per sample: 16
Please advise
Thanks in advance

Hello, have you ever tried to use NAudio library to play gsm audio file?

Hi. the code above is actually using NAudio, but I cannot figure out how to make the file to a html5 playable file. Thanks!

Imports NAudio.Wave
Imports System.IO

Function ConvertGsm610ToPcm(inputBytes As Byte()) As Byte()
    Using gsmStream As New MemoryStream(inputBytes)
        Using gsmReader As New WaveFileReader(gsmStream)
            If gsmReader.WaveFormat.Encoding = WaveFormatEncoding.Gsm610 Then
                Using pcmStream As New MemoryStream()
                    Dim gsmToPcmStream As New WaveFormatConversionStream(New WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1), gsmReader)
                    gsmToPcmStream.CopyTo(pcmStream)
                    Return pcmStream.ToArray()
                End Using
            Else
                Return inputBytes ' Return original bytes if not GSM610 (optional)
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End Function

in HTML file
    <audio controls>
        <source src="data:audio/wav;base64,<!-- Base64 encoded PCM data -->" type="audio/wav">
    </audio>

    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            var audioElement = document.querySelector('audio');
            var pcmData = "<%= Convert.ToBase64String(pcmData) %>";
            audioElement.src = "data:audio/wav;base64," + pcmData;
        };
    </script>

Exactly you should convert GSM audio to PCM audio to play gsm file in html.
I hope this code will help your problem.

Hi. Thanks for your input. As I wrote in the question. I cannot use "Using gsmReader As New WaveFileReader(gsmStream)", since it cause an error:  "Not a WAVE file - no RIFF header"

Maybe, is it just raw data?
So, you should try to decode it by using stream.
Please, check several first bytes like in this header of ".wav":
52 49 46 46 7C 98 01 00 57 41 56 45 66 6D 74 20 14 00 00 00 31 00 01 00 40 1F 00 00 59 06 00 00 41 00

where:
52 49 46 46 = "RIFF",
7C 98 01 00 = "104572" = file size - header,
57 41 56 45 = "WAVE",
66 6D 74 20 = "fmt ",
...

